# How to add vertical scroll bar in each tree node of a angular nested tree?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-tree-component

[Angular Nested Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv6SZ.png)

How can I add vertical scroll bar in each tree node and child node?

Comment: You can use overflow: auto , or overflow: scroll in the container which has list of items. And then define a fixed height for your container.
For more clarification I would suggest to share a plnkr link with code example.

Comment: @Sarat Nath Did you got any solution?